# Should I send an addendum/erratum due to single error in sign?

Tags: journals, writing, errors-erratum

I was reading my own paper published in 2018 and I noticed that in one of the sections I wrote **"<"** instead **">"** to indicate greater than or greater value, although the preceding sentences is clearly stating/suggesting that it should be **">"** greater. I was wondering if I should write or send an erratum to the journal editor?

Comment: If it is on arxiv, you could correct the typo and put the corrected version online.

Comment: It's already published.

Comment: @Adam's advice still holds: Technical reports can be modified (publications cannot)

Comment: You can have the corrected version on the arxiv, with a comment saying that typos are corrected compared to the published version. (I have even added a whole appendix to the arxiv version of a published paper once!) Hopefully, arxiv will become the go-to website to find papers instead of journals website, and so people will only read the corrected version. It is already the case in some communities.

Answer (score 5):

No.

I would guess almost every mathematics paper (mine included) has at least one typo of this magnitude.

As you indicate, readers can easily correct the typo for themselves, and some might even do it subconsciously.

Answer (score 1):

On some journal websites it is possible to comment on specific publications. If your journal allows this, you could simply post a comment pointing out the minor error (I have occasionally seen authors do this).